# Modulus of same number returns different results

Tags: c++

```
int a=032302;
cout<<a%10<<endl; // output 6
int b=32302;
cout<<b%10<<endl;  // output 2
```

I was trying to get the unit's place of a number but while coding i found a weird thing, the first and the second no are technically same, however they both output different results.

The first one returns 6 while the second one 2 , am i missing  something here?

Comment: Literals of numbers starting with '0' are in base 8.

Comment: Base 8, actually.

Comment: Right, corrected.

Comment: The above comments are correct, see the various [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) including prefixes and suffixes.

Comment: How's [`13506`](http://ideone.com/VMuZCE) and `32302` the same number? ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: Run `cout << a << endl;` for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks everyone, got it.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting a numeral with 0 (zero) in c/c++ means it is an octal (base 8) number. Thus 032302 is 13506 in decimal notation. Hence, the last digit is 6 and that is what you get from your modulus operation.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact that

```
int a = 032302;
```

and

```
int b = 13506;
```

are holding the same integer value since variable **a** is init as octal literal

then is correct that

**a%10** returns 6 same as  **b%10** returns 6